# Binding inside ContentControl not working

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm building a graphical designer, based upon an [article by Sukram in CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24681/WPF-Diagram-Designer-Part-4). I'm now trying to extend it so that each item on the canvas binds to a different ViewModel object - i.e. I'm setting the DataContext for each item.

Every item on the designer is actually a ContentControl, into which is placed a different template (based upon which toolbox item was dragged onto the canvas). So I have a template containing a TextBox, and I have a ViewModel object containing a Name property, and I bind the Text property of the TextBox to the Name property of the ViewModel, and ... nothing. I've checked the visual tree with Snoop, and it confirms that the DataContext of the TextBox is the ViewModel object. Yet the TextBox remains empty. And if I modify the (empty) Text in the TextBox, the Name property in the ViewModel does not change. So it looks like the binding is not being applied (or has been removed somehow).

I've found a few posts which talk about the ContentControl messing around with the DataContext and Content properties, but I'm not sure how applicable they all are. The code sets the ContentControl.Content as follows:

```
newItem = new ContentControl();
ControlTemplate template = toolbox.GetTemplate();
UIElement element = template.LoadContent() as UIElement;
ViewModelItem viewModel = new ViewModelItem() { Name = "Bob" };

newItem.Content = element;
newItem.DataContext = viewModel;
```

and the XAML for the template is:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="100">
        <TextBox Text={Binding Name}/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Snoop shows that the TextBox has a DataContext, and if I Delve that DataContext I can see that it has a Name property whose value is "Bob". So why does the TextBox remain empty? Snoop allows me to change that Name property, but the TextBox remains empty.

What am I doing wrong?

---

A few more details. I've set the VS2010 Debug DataBinding option for the OutputWindow to Verbose, which seems to show that the binding is all being attempted *before* I set the DataContext. Is it possible that the change to the DataContext is not being recognised?

---

I've just found this post [DataTemplate.LoadContent does not preserve bindings](http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/b98a576a-b4df-4b9c-9061-deb847ce847a&ei=HyvqUIDXEeeXiAfjtYH4Bg&usg=AFQjCNF1tEqrwBAEzpLtou_NDiThBndW3A&sig2=0FrgCQMwwhZ556v5q2SD8g) - apparently DataTemplate.LoadContent does not preserve bindings. So it looks like I have to write my own version of LoadContent().

---

I've realised that the template has come through a XamlWriter, which apparently strips all bindings. This wouldn't be helping.

---

I've not been able to fix the DataTemplate.LoadContent(), but I realised that I didn't actually need a DataTemplate, since the XamlWriter / XamlReader was already instantiating the UI element that I was after. I found a fix to make the XamlWriter write all the bindings [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27158/XamlWriter-and-Bindings-Serialization), and after that it all works.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to tell the binding in the `ControlTemplate` to look at the `TemplatedParent`, as is mentioned in [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/d3c939ae-d5a2-442c-906b-5fd53043566e)?

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Either that, or try to use a `DataTemplate` instead.

I can't test this at the moment, so I might just be guessing here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work. I've also tried binding the DataContext to the element inside the ContentControl, which Snoop shows makes it to the TextBox, but that doesn't work either. The difficulty with all of this is that I don't know how to debug this binding issue. I can see that the DataContext of the TextBox is correct using Snoop, but I don't know how to find out why the binding won't bind - no exceptions get raised and there's nothing in the Output window. All that's left seems to be randomly trying various different types of binding parameters.

Comment: Yeah, debugging binding issues in WPF is not easy. I don't know of any tools to help with that, other than the `Output` window in VS which sometimes shows binding error messages. If you can't get the control template to work, you may have to go with a `DataTemplate` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `DataTemplate`, as bde suggests.

You are trying to put some UI on your own *data* (ViewModel), and this is what *Data*-Templates are meant for (`ControlTemplate` is usually what you use if you want to [change how e.g. a `Button` looks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30994/Introduction-to-WPF-Templates)).

Change your code to use `ContentControl.ContentTemplate` with a `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Width="100">
        <TextBox Text={Binding Name}/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Code-behind:

```
newItem = new ContentControl();
//NOTE: .GetTemplate() needs to return a DataTemplate, and not a ControlTemplate:
newItem.ContentTemplate = toolbox.GetTemplate();

ViewModelItem viewModel = new ViewModelItem() { Name = "Bob" };

newItem.Content = viewModel;
newItem.DataContext = viewModel;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - it makes sense so I've done it but it makes no difference. Snoops shows that the TextBox has the correct DataContext, but the Name is still not displayed. Any other ideas?

Comment: How do you load the template in `toolbox.GetTemplate()`? Could you post that function as well?

Comment: GetTemplate() is just a regular attached property, viz:

Comment: `public static readonly DependencyProperty DesignerElementProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("DesignerElement", typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(DesignerItem));
  
        public static FrameworkElement GetDesignerElement(UIElement element)  
        {
            Object value = element.GetValue(DesignerElementProperty);  
            return (FrameworkElement)value;  
        }`

Comment: That's the code for some `DesignerElement` property, not the `GetTemplate()` method. I'm not sure I understand your solution, but reading your updated question I see that you've fixed it, so I guess it's all good then :)